# How to limit feed?

Tags: php, rss, feed

I'm building a website to learn PHP and am making a combine-rss-feeds into one feed that I can display on my website.

Here's the code:

```
<?php

    class Feed_Amalgamator
    {
        public $urls = array();
        public $data = array();

        public function addFeeds( array $feeds )
        {
            $this->urls = array_merge( $this->urls, array_values($feeds) );
        }

        public function grabRss()
        {
            foreach ( $this->urls as $feed )
            {
                $data = @new SimpleXMLElement( $feed, 0, true );
                if ( !$data )
                    throw new Exception( 'Could not load: ' . $feed );
                foreach ( $data->channel->item as $item )
                {
                    $this->data[] = $item;
                }
            }
        }

        public function amalgamate()
        {
            shuffle( $this->data );
            $temp = array();
            foreach ( $this->data as $item )
            {
                if ( !in_array($item->link, $this->links($temp)) )
                {
                    $temp[] = $item;
                }
            }
            $this->data = $temp;
            shuffle( $this->data );
        }

        private function links( array $items )
        {
            $links = array();
            foreach ( $items as $item )
            {
                $links[] = $item->link;
            }
            return $links;
        }
    }

    /********* Example *********/

    $urls = array( 'http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/sportonline_uk_edition/football/teams/m/man_city/rss.xml', 'http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/sportonline_uk_edition/football/teams/l/liverpool/rss.xml' );

    try
    {
        $feeds = new Feed_Amalgamator;
        $feeds->addFeeds( $urls );
        $feeds->grabRss();
        $feeds->amalgamate();
    }
    catch ( exception $e )
    {
        die( $e->getMessage() );
    }

    foreach ( $feeds->data as $item ) :
    extract( (array) $item );
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a>
    <p><?php echo $description; ?></p>
    <p><em><?php echo $pubDate; ?></em></p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

It's a great script, works perfectly, but it takes up quite a lot of space on my website. How can I limit it to only displaying,  say 5 results, kind of like a MySQL limit?

Comment: You want a total of five results, or five results per URL?

Comment: @j08691, 5 total results

Comment: or if its easier than 2 results from each url. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your foreach to a for(i=0; i<5; i++) loop. The other possibility: introduce a counter variable that you increment and test at the start of the foreach. Break out of the loop when it hits 5.